# How do I prevent images structured as a horizontal list from wrapping?

Tags: css, image, word-wrap

I have a row of distinct images that I want to use as a banner. Upon resizing, I *don't* want the last image(s) to wrap. I've done prerequisite google and search on stackoverflow; the examples I found were regarding text, not images.

Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pHytx/

The most relevant part of the code is probably the CSS:

```
#slidebanners {                                                                                                       
    width:100%;                                                                                                       
}                                                                                                                     

#slidebanner ul{                                                                                                      
    padding: 0;                                                                                                       
    margin: 0;                                                                                                        
    overflow: hidden;                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                     
#slidebanner li{                                                                                                      
    float: left;                                                                                                      
}                                                                                                                     

#slidebanner img{                                                                                                     
    height: 200px;                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                     

.page-header {                                                                                                        
    font-size: 2em;                                                                                                   
    padding: .5em;                                                                                                    
    margin-top: 15px;                                                                                                 
}
```

The problem with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311248/how-to-prevent-images-blocks-from-wrapping) is that it doesn't get rid of the gap between the pictures; float gets rid of that gap. I *could* add a negative left margin, but that has weird effects because the negative margin gets applied unevenly (i.e. the rightmost image needs the most negative margin, but this affects the size of the leftmost image)

Answer (score 1):

It's best to go for `white-space: nowrap` combined with `display: inline-block`, as shown in the accepted answer to the question you linked to.

The problem then becomes how to remove the gaps between the `li`s.

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pHytx/4/

I went with removing the whitespace between the elements in the HTML.

Some people don't like editing their HTML to remove the gaps. To those people I say: *deal with it*. This is the easiest way to remove the gaps.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="media/images/slides/olympic-1.jpg" />
    </li><li>
        <img src="media/images/slides/olympic-2.jpg" />
    </li><li>
        <img src="media/images/slides/olympic-3.jpg" />
    </li><li>
        <img src="media/images/slides/olympic-4.jpg" />
    </li><li>
        <img src="media/images/slides/olympic-5.jpg" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

```css
#slidebanner ul {
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#slidebanner li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#slidebanner img {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

---

To hopefully stop these pesky downvotes, here is a working implementation of the `display: table-cell` approach, thanks to user1721135 for the idea.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/pHytx/5/

```css
#slidebanner {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#slidebanner ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
#slidebanner li {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}
#slidebanner img {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.page-header {
    clear: both;
    font-size: 2em;
    padding: .5em;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't know that the space between the li elements actually gets rendered. Can anyone explain *why* this happens? I tried editing my structure and just laying out the img tags next to one another and it exhibited the same problem; there was a space between each img that could only be removed if I removed the carriage return between each of them.

Comment: thats a very fragile solution.

Comment: @Avery: The `li` elements are inline, which means they are treated similarly to text. For the same reason there is a space between the words in `<b>hello world</b>`, there is a space between the inline-block `li` elements.

Answer (score 1):

For this you can use the exotic `display:table-cell;`

See Demo:
http://jsbin.com/OxEPuJi/1/edit

Basically display:table-cell; prevents elements to drop on the next line. EVER!

And it also forces them to be next to each other without float.

Codes:

```
.img {
display:table-cell;
}
```

I apply this to the wrapper element which holds each image in my demo.

Comment: Also a reasonable solution. You should include the code from your demo in your answer.

Comment: Well, this was good until you edited the HTML to remove the `li`s and broke it in for example WebKit browsers.